# How do I create profile pictures on website from Google Sites?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I want the students to create their own student profiles where they can say a bit about them and list the books they have read. I am creating a website that is familiar with Good Reads. In addition, I would also want each student would make their own profile and the administrators would post their comments. Is this possible on Google Sites?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can see some useful resources [here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/available-web-apps/awesome-tables/people-directory). Also, bear in mind that broad questions like this are not meant for StackOverflow.

Comment: Dear ZektorH, where should I instead ask this question since my "broad question" are not ment for StackOverflow?

Comment: Hello @julius-cool, stack overflow is not a place to request other's program for you or to ask questions regarding feasibility (i.e. Is it possible to (...)?).
Read these articles [1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to familiarize yourself with the rules before posting!